# Docker in Docker dind connecting to ddev container within compose network from host maschine

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ddev, docker-in-docker

I'm currently working on setting up a ddev typo3 webpage running in a [ubuntu dind](https://github.com/cruizba/ubuntu-dind) container to get around the installation requirements for ddev on windows.

I have previously tested connecting to an nginx container within the dind container, which worked as expected. With this, nginx was served on localhost:80 on the host.

```
#host
docker run --rm -it --privileged -p 80:8080 ubuntu-dind

#container
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web nginx
```

After successfully setting up and starting ddev, the following containers are now running inside my dind container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                                                  NAMES
cf695c8e2ed9   drud/ddev-router:v1.21.4-built                             "/app/docker-entrypo…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)   127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:443->443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:8025-8026->8025-8026/tcp, 127.0.0.1:8036-8037->8036-8037/tcp   ddev-router
6d26ecd91adf   drud/ddev-webserver:20230207_fix_nvm-recruiting-built      "/start.sh"              3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)   8025/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32772->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32771->443/tcp                                                            ddev-recruiting-web
5e10c98eb2e7   phpmyadmin:5                                               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes             80/tcp                                                                                                                 ddev-recruiting-dba
8e3a5254605d   drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.4-recruiting-built   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)   127.0.0.1:32768->3306/tcp                                                                                              ddev-recruiting-db
68f7527750ab   drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.21.4-built                          "/entry.sh ssh-agent"    4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (healthy)                                                                                                                          ddev-ssh-agent
```

The next step would now be to connect to http://recruiting.ddev.site:8036/ the site is reachable from within the dind container, but im unsure of how to connect to this address from the host.

I have fired up my dind container as follows:
`docker run --rm -it --privileged -v ${PWD}/project:/usr/src/project -p 80:8036 dindu`
Attempting to map port 8036 of the container to port 80 on the host.
Testing to connect to port 8036 inside the container reaches:

```
root@57fcae15337a:/usr/src/project# curl 127.0.0.1:8036
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>503: No ddev back-end site available</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 35em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>503: No ddev back-end site available.</h1>
<p>This is the ddev-router container: There is no back-end webserver at the URL you specified. You may want to use "ddev start" to start the site.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And only gets an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from the host, so it's there have to be some additional steps im missing. I don't believe my problem is ddev specific and has more to do with me being somewhat inexperienced with docker networking.

How do I forward an address, like http://recruiting.ddev.site, instead of a simple port to the host machine?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. What does DinD have to do with this? Why are you running the container separately instead of as an extra service, as in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/ ? Why are you fiddling with the dba container? If you want DDEV to work inside your DinD (as it does just fine on gitpod) then just install it and use it there...  DDEV's gitpod image might help you, drud/ddev-gitpod-base:20221215, also just try DDEV in gitpod. https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation/#gitpod

Comment: Discord may be a better place to get more interactive help and figure out what you are trying to accomplish, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: @rfay After re-reading it I admit it came off as a bit unclear, my apologies. I wanted a Linux environment to work with, hence the dind. Im unsure of how to access the webpage on the host, since its not just a simple port as with the Nginx example. I will also check out the discord, thank you very much for the recommendation!

Comment: You certainly don't need dind to use DDEV with Linux. There are standard installation techniques, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/docker-installation/#linux and https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation/#linux